# JQuery: How to use the Each method to check values in all form input element

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to JQuery:

Okay I am confused and have tried all variations, including what I have read in books and the JQuery API.

I have the following sample ***Mark-up***:

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <label>*Enter Input A:
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="inputA" name="inputA" />
    </label>
    <label>*Enter Input B:
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="inputB" name="inputB" />
    </label>
    <label>*Enter Input C:
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="inputC" name="inputC" />
    </label>
    <label>*Enter Input D:
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="inputD" name="inputD" />
    </label>
</form>
<p class="myText">Sample Text</p>
```

When the page loads and I tab through the `fields/textboxes`, the paragraph color changes.
Which is what I want: `blur function`.

***What I don't understand:***

The paragraph does not change unless I type a value into the last `textbox` **inputD**.
Why? I need the paragraph to change if there is a value in any of the boxes.
Does this hold only one value? `($(element).val() == '')`?

Here is the JQ:

```
 $('#myForm :input[type="text"]').blur(function () {
     $('#myForm input[type="text"]').each(function (i, element) {
         if ($(element).val() == '') {
             $(".myText").css("color", "#F00")
         } else {
             $(".myText").css("color", "#9A9A9A")
         }
     });
 });
```

A fiddle is here: [JSfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wmrh6/9/)

Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Just as an aside, no need for the params in the `.each(function (i, element)` code, a simple `.each(function() {` does the trick. Similarly, just use `$(this)` in the if test. [See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hQBg/), which incorporates PSL's solution.

Comment: @gibberish in-fact `this.value` is sufficient..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not breaking out of the loop once you meet the desired condition. Instead you are looping through all textboxes and eventually if last one does not have any value it will be set to red color no matter whichever prev ones has values as that is the last one in the iteration. Instead you can break out of `.each()` loop  using `return false;`

```
 $('#myForm :input[type="text"]').blur(function () {
     $('#myForm input[type="text"]').each(function () {
         if (this.value == '') {
             $(".myText").css("color", "#F00")
         } else {
             $(".myText").css("color", "#9A9A9A");
                 return false;
         }
     });
 });
```

For that matter you could reduce it down to:

```
 $('#myForm :input[type="text"]').blur(function () {
     $('.myText').css('color', function () { //use the css function callback
         return $('#myForm input[type="text"]').filter(function () { //Use filter to return the textboxes which has value
             return this.value != ''
         }).length == 0 ? "#F00" : "#9A9A9A"; // set the color accordingly

     });
 });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DW3LY/)**

Comment: Thanks my friend. I have been struggling with this: I was reading JQuery Missing Manual and never read anything about what you just showed me about breaking from the loop or the other methods of doing this. I guess in time I'll become better: Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code, please check fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Wmrh6/11/

you should change paragraph color when u break out of the loop:

```
   if(changed)$(".myText").css("color", "#9A9A9A");else
          $(".myText").css("color", "#F00");
```